Non-normal data transformation
I am currently trying to transform my non-normal data so that I can run glmm models for some research. My data is behavior related so nothing about that is normally ditributed but I am currently stuck on how to transform my data next. I have tried sqrt and log10 so far but when I test for uniformity the graphs are still showing that they aren't normal. My data is also VERY zero inflated. I'm still newish to r studio so I only know so much, but could I somehow use a negative binomial family?
For clarification on my data, I work in behavioral biology so my data is in seconds. I am looking how physical stress and residency status impacts territorial behavior. For the graphs below I also included cover object types as a random variable. In the code at the bottom, treatment just means stressed or nonstressed, and status is resident or intruder. My trials were 10 minutes total so I was recording 8 different behaviors but my model I only have one listed at a time to avoid overcomplication. each behavior could have the lowest time of 0 or the highest or 600 seconds. I am still very new to r studio and especially transforming data so I hope this enough information because I need all the help I can get!
I performed a log10 and sqrt at the advice of a professor. The same professor advised me to run a general linear mixed model with the data instead of the mann-whitney tests that I was originally using.
These are my graphs before trying any transformations:


Any advice on how I should transform my data so I can run a glmm would be so helpful!
I tried sqrt and log10 transformations. I believe they partially work but do not fix every issue with the data.
Here are my log10 graphs: This is from using the log10 transformation on my model zero inflation with log10 transformation


Here are my sqrt graphs: sqrt transformation sqrt zero inflation


Also here is the code I am using to get these graphs and the model. I work with salamanders and all of this data is on their aggressive behaviors.
SimOutput.sallys <- glmmTMB(sqrt(ATR + .1) ~ Treatment * Status + (1 | CoverObj), data = sallys) 
SQRTsimulationoutput1 <- simulateResiduals(SimOutput.sallys, n = 1000, plot = TRUE)
plot(SQRTsimulationoutput1) 
testUniformity(simulationOutput = SQRTsimulationoutput1) 
testDispersion(SQRTsimulationoutput1) 
testZeroInflation(SQRTsimulationoutput1)


Is you DV a count, or a continuous value? Also, if you have a lot of 0s (or any) how did you take logs? Also, it's the residuals that matter, but you show those.   There are a variety of nonlinear multilevel models, but it's hard to say which is best without more info.

Welcome to the site. As the other comment says, please try to give some detail about the study design, eg. when you say “behaviors” are you counting the number of aggressive behaviors in some unit time? Using a rating tool? What are your data? Also, are your diagnostic plots from ordinary regression? Glmm?

This probably won't help but it will be easy to try. Instead of using elapsed time in secods as your dependent variable, take the reciprocal which is proportional to velocity. Maybe those transformed values will be better behaved.

The QQ plot of the DHARMa residuals seems to suggest some very strange behavior. Can you perhaps plot the raw data scatterplots between the predictors and outcome?
